# The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency: "jest": "24.9.0"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, npm, jestjs

I have updated **create-react-app** and created the project again but i still have that message when run `npm test`:

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "jest": "24.9.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\saher\Desktop\react-test\test\node_modules\jest (version: 26.4.2)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\saher\Desktop\react-test\test\node_modules\jest is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed
jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.
```

This is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.4",
    "jest": "^26.4.2"
  }
}
```

I tried everything possible to make it work, but the only thing that make it work is downgrading jest to the recommended version in the message

```
npm i --save-dev jest@24.9.0
```

But i don't like that solution as i want to use the latest version of jest, i want to know how to solve this problem in the way that i can use the latest version of jest

Comment: Have you tried updating your devDependency inside the package.json file ?
`"jest": "^24.9.0"`

Comment: version `24.9.0` is not the latest version, i downgraded it to that version and worked, but i need to use the latest version

Comment: I just checked create-react-app and react-scripts dependencies and now they're using "jest": "26.4.2". Trying downgrad on react-scripts to 3.4.1 maybe ? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/package.json#L3

Comment: @ManuelV.Battan still the same problem, using npm can be a hell sometimes